# In Xojo, can a desktop app be converted to a web app?

Tags: web-applications, vb6, converters, desktop-application, xojo

I am basically using Xojo to rebuilding another program previously built in Visual Basic 6. My superior wants me to build this as a desktop app, because that is what the VB6 code originally was. After that, we are going to convert the desktop app to a web app. I need to know if this is a reliable plan.

The xojo website says that code can be shared between desktop apps and web apps.  However, I need to copy an entire desktop app over to a web app.

In Xojo, can a desktop app be converted to a web app? What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Xojo code can be shared between targets but the UI controls will have to be redone.

With all that said, we (BKeeney Software) have an internal utility that converts as much of the desktop controls as we can to Web Edition controls.  It's not pretty as it misses any subclassed controls.

It's not a commercial product but we did convert one of our existing desktop projects to web edition.  We might be able to help as a consulting project (sorry for the plug for consulting services).

Answer (score 1):

If you design your desktop app appropriately up front, you'll be able to share code with a future web app. You will not be able to share any UI layouts, however.

For some guidance, check out the *Xojo User Guide Book 4: Development, Chapter 3: Web Development, Section 2: Porting Desktop Applications*.